# how to extract option 43 from systemd-networkd's dhcp client?

Tags: debian, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

Just like how dhclient captures dhcp response and stores it in env, is there a way to capture information like option 43 from systemd-networkd's DHCP client and store it in env ?
I have proxy URL stored in option 43 and I need to access that information.

tcpdump shows response has vendor 43 data, but I am unable to extract it via scripts or from env.

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like systemd-networkd's DHCP client does not store the DHCP lease or any information on disk unlike isc-dhcp-client which stores lease and vendor options

Comment: This looks like it should be additional information in the _question_, as it doesn't provide an answer of how to get the values you need.  Please edit the question instead.